# Input max-width: 100% not working in table

Tags: css, input, html-table, width, responsive

I'm trying to achieve responsive input width inside a table, but `input {max-width:100%;}` is not working in table. For example:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Title</td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Foo</td><td><input type="text" size="8"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bar</td><td><input type="text" size="200"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The max-width property don't work well with percentage. Please you should use width property to achieve what you are trying to do here.

Just try this for input and it should work -

```
width: CALC(100%);
max-width: 80px; (or whatever you want)
```

Check if it works!